# TableView Display Files in Documents Folder

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm just starting to learn how to code for iOS and Swift and I'm trying to figure out TableViews.

Specifically, I'd like my table view to be able to display files in my app's document folder. (This is the document folder that is accessible to the user in the Files app)
My understanding is that I'd have to use NSFileManager? to get this data but I'm unable to find any tutorials explaining how to get this data back into a tableview so that the user can select a file (pdf or jpg) to display.

Can someone guide me on the right path on how to solve this?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Here is how to "Recursively list all dirs and files in a iOS app's documents directory" but it's in Objective-C: [source](https://gist.github.com/dantheman213/3d4b6644d127d26d8ef5).

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to do this in Swift?